# Java on GPU: Complete Method directly on GPUin plain Java

Tags: java, gpu

Firstly: Is it possible to use Java and let it (partly) run on or use GPUs?
And if it's possible, is it possible to use the normal Java syntax and not using special cuda or opencl syntax?

I want just take my coded java source and let it run with the smallest changes possible on GPUs.

I would greatly appreciate code samples.

Comment: http://gavab.escet.urjc.es/wiki/download/JavaOpenCL/Documentacion/JCUDA.pdf

Comment: A close option might be Tilera which supports Java on its 100 core processors.

Answer (score 12):

Consider Aparapi http://aparapi.github.io/.  It attempts to convert bytecode to OpenCL at runtime. So you can code for your GPU in pure Java.

Full disclosure, I am the Aparapi lead developer.

Comment: Hmmm, will have a look, thanks! :)
So I will need to buy a newlaptop with gpu even earlier! :)

Comment: went to see your github page. Is there a Hello World tutorial somewhere ? I want to use GPU to do some crypto computations. in Java

Comment: @gfrost actually no, it cannot (Aparapi 3.0.0): it does not support all sorts of JAVA stuff, like JAVA objects and things - it constantly complains about it (I had to really change and compromise my code to somehow fit yet still not made it), from my point of view it is only good for arrays and that's it - you cannot simply take your existing code as whole and let it compute on GPU using Aparapi if that is what this post is about, no way (or I did not understood it). On the other hand: implementation is the easiest one compared to the other stuff of this sort, like JCuda, which is great

Comment: Sorry it's been a few years but this showed up in my inbox so I figured I would respond ;)
Java's object layout (objects strewn across the heap) makes it hard to achieve your goal of having Java objects just work on the GPU. We really need coherent memory between CPU and GPU (achieved with a hack of Aparapi using AMD's HSA devices).  Lots of work has been done in this area to try to achieve this, and possibly Project Panama from Java may help.

Answer (score 11):

The Rootbeer GPU Compiler supports running arbitrary Java code on the GPU. It is more full featured than Aparapi. Rootbeer supports arbirary object graphs of any type.

It was just released open source on my github account: 
https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1

Comment: I would very like to test it - is there generated JAR somewhere (not individual src .java files) + some sorts of simple tutorials/examples, please?

Answer (score 8):

There are several Java bindings to CUDA and OpenCL ([jcuda.org](http://www.jcuda.org/), [jocl.org](http://www.jocl.org/), something else also called [jocl](http://jogamp.org/jocl/www/)) but these are all just ways to get CUDA or OpenCL code running on the GPU via Java and require you to write your code specifically for that. I don't think there is an easy way to run an arbitrary multi-threaded Java program on the GPU with just minor changes to the code.

What does your Java program do that you want to run on the GPU?

You have to take into account that the architecture of a GPU is quite different than that of a CPU; cores on a GPU are not general-purpose cores that can do anything and work independently, as in an Intel x86 CPU. To really take advantage of the specific SIMD architecture of a GPU, your code has to be written with that architecture in mind.

Comment: Hi,
it's simulating a rocket trajectory, simply integrating the movement. And I want to bring it on GPU, because it's for my Boinc project http://aerospaceresearch.net/constellation/ and some users would really like to see a GPU app. And when it's faster, it's even better.
Andreas

Comment: Is the algorithm massively parallelizable? You could study one of those CUDA or OpenCL bindings, learn about how GPUs work, and see how you can implement your algorithm in a way that is suited for the GPU. It's not as simple as just somehow recompiling your existing Java program...

Answer (score 4):

TornadoVM is a plug-in to OpenJDK that allows programmers to automatically run Java programs on heterogeneous hardware. TornadoVM currently targets OpenCL-compatible devices and it runs on multi-core CPUs, GPUs (NVIDIA and AMD), Intel integrated GPUs, and Intel FPGAs.
Take a look here:  https://github.com/beehive-lab/TornadoVM

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on http://code.google.com/p/java-gpu/.

It compiles pure java code into kernels, with only using annotations.

Comment: Java-GPU is quite old - AparAPI is much more frequently updated.